# Phaser game only small line on iOS8

Tags: html, ios8, game-engine

I made a game in phaser a HTML 5 game framework/engine.
This games works perfectly on all phones and browsers now.
The only problem now is that on iOS 8 the game is transformed into a line at the bottom of my browser. Sometimes i can see the line on my iPhone or iPad and see the texture of my game.

this is what happens: http://puu.sh/bCrEs/338bf0d7a1.png

I don't know why or how to fix this.
So i hope one of you guys can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ah interesting my game wasn't loading at all on iOS8. I'll check and see if it's doing the single line like yours is.